# How do I extrapolate probability distributions from a single distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, extrapolation

If I have 3 fair 6 sided dice, and 1 throw consists of rolling all 3 of them, how do I extrapolate the distribution of roll values of each individual die for a specific sum from the distribution of roll values of each individual die from a specific sum. The wording is a bit messy so I'll explain further.

I have calculated the distribution of 1,2,3,4,5,6s (possible dice values) for the throws which sum to 10. From this distribution, how could I extrapolate for the distribution of lets say 11. Could I extrapolate all the way to 18?

[Probability distribution of dice given they sum to 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5lQm.png)

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your question. Do you mean you want to get the conditional probability of the possible dice throws when you condition on them having a certain sum?

Comment: @JairTaylor If I understand what you're saying correctly, then yes that's exactly it!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  My best guess is that you are just asking for the probability that the sum of three fair dice is $i$ for $i\in \{3, \cdots, 18\}$.  Is that it?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Perhaps it would help to work the same problem (whatever it may be) for two fair dice.  Presumably you have done that case, yes?

Comment: @lulu I've just edited it to attach the probability distribution of dice given they sum to 9. Hopefully that makes it clearer as to what I'm trying to find.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I have no idea what, say, "$1$" refers to in that chart.  Is there some reason you can't simply state the calculation you want to perform?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like $P(X_1 = k | X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = n)$?

Comment: Are you possibly asking:  "suppose we throw three dice (a red one, a blue one, and a green one) and we observe that the sum is $k$.  What, then, is the probability that the red die is $i$ for $i\in \{1, \cdots, 6\}$?" ?

Comment: @lulu Okay, I'll explain how I achieved the probability value of 1 in that chart. I rolled dice in sets of 3. I did that 1000 times. Then I counted the number of 1s that were rolled in any set of 3 which summed to 9. I then divided the number of 1s by the number of individual dice rolled (1000*3 as I did 1000 sets of 3). Hopefully that clarifies what I'm after because I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: So, for instance, if the sum were $4$ then we know the dice came up $1,1,2$ in some order, so the probability that the red one came up $1$ is $\frac 23$.  The probability that it came up $2$ is $\frac 13$, and all other values have probability $0$.  Is that what you intend?

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes that's sort of what I'm after, but instead of the X_1 = k, I'm after any of X_1, X_2, X_3 =k

Comment: Yes, the distribution for each die is the same, of course.  So, for any value, $k$, simply list all possible ordered rolls that sum to $k$ and count those that have the desired value in, say, the first place.

Comment: @lulu Yes that's exactly it! If I have a distribution of that for a specific sum, how would I extrapolate for a larger sum?

Comment: You can go faster if you work the problem for two dice first.

Comment: There is no "extrapolation" here.  Rather, you can build it up recursively from the results for two dice.

Comment: @lulu I see, I'll attempt that then. I appreciate your effort in trying to decipher my question, as well as your help.

Comment: To get a sum of $9$, for instance, consider each value for the first toss.  If the first toss is $1$, then the next two must sum to $8$ and so on.